# Yii2 вывод в сайдбаре

Tags: yii2, view, activerecord, model

Как правильно в Yii2 выводить данные в "сквозных" блоках ? К примеру у нас есть сайдбар, в нем нужно вывести последние новости на сайте. Сейчас приходится добавлять метод в модели, вроде

```
public static function getLatestNews()
{
  return $latest_news; 
}
```

И дергать его в представлении, вроде

```
$news = Model::getLatestNews();
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает что такой подход не верен, есть еще варианты решения подобных задач ?

Comment: Все просто - сделайте виджет. Тогда в его контроллере будет обращение к модели, а во вьюхе просто вывод шаблона с переменными

Comment: В контроллере виджета ?

Comment: Да. Это я его условно контроллером обозвал. Там на самом деле методы `init` и `run` в которых происходит обработка и вывод.

Comment: Ну про это я в курсе, думал просто может там как-то правильнее cделать можно. Ведь по сути в виджете придется дергать тот же статичный метод модели ну или делать запрос в самом виджете :(

Comment: Ну виджет на то и виджет, что он отображает что-то такое блочное в любом удобном месте сайта, при этом дергать может любые методы откуда угодно и можно прописывать любую логику, хоть по варке крокодила в кастрюле.

Comment: :) Понял, спасибо. Оформите отдельным ответом, приму как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в Yii для таких целей есть понятие виджета (Widget)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-widget.html

Comment: Спасибо, осталось разобраться с этим http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525139/yii2-widget-data-foreach

Answer (score 1):

В первом yii есть понятие `helpers` и `components`, в чистом php есть `traits`, не хотите дублировать код, то смотрите в их сторону, кстати что значит сквозные?

Comment: Речь о Yii2. Хэлперы, компоненты, есть конечно, но сам факт обращения к модели в представлении мне не очень нравиться.

Сквозные, значит выводятся на всех страницах сайта, к примеру меню в шапке или тот же сайдбар.

Comment: Модель заведует логикой, для того она туда и вынесена, чтобы получать в отображении готовый результат, а не пилить эту же логику на фронтенде.
Можете сделать модель обёртку, менеджер к которому будете обращаться из отображений. Тут совсем не важен фреймворк а правильность использования MVC и паттернов.