# Yii2 widget data foreach

Tags: yii2, виджет

Есть виджет вида

```
class ItemsWidget extends Widget
{
    public $items;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->items = Items::find()->asArray()->all();
        ob_start();
        // что-то вроде этого, но не работает
        for ($i=0; $i < count ($this->items) ; $i++ )
        { 
           extract($this->items[$i]);
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return Html::encode( $content );
    }
}
```

В представлении используется шаблонизатор [Smarty](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-smarty), хотя роли это не играет вроде как в данном случае.

```
{ItemsWidget assign='widget'}
    // как обойтись без цикла здесь ?
    <div>{$widget.items.title}</div>
{/ItemsWidget}
```

Каким образом можно перебрать массив и вернуть готовый блок кода ?

Comment: Как я понял, вы пользуетесь шаблонизатором. C документациией Twig по циклам можете ознакомиться [тут](http://x-twig.ru/tags/for/)

Comment: Это смарти. Как выводить все это дело в шаблонизаторе я в курсе, просто код вида 
`{ItemsWidget assign='widget'}
    {foreach $widget.items as $item}
        <div>{$item.title}</div>
    {/foreach}
{/ItemsWidget}`

меня как-то смущает. Я так понимаю есть способ сделать это в файле ItemsWidget.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вы не особо понимаете до конца, как работает виджет:

Например в папке **frontend/widgets** создаю файл **Header.php** c неким содержимым:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\widgets;

use common\models\Articles;
use yii\base\Widget;

class Header extends Widget
{
  public function init()
  {
    parent::init();

  }
  public function run()
  {
    $rows = Articles::find()->all();

    return $this->render('header', [
      'rows' => $rows
    ]);
  }
}
```

Т.е. я в $rows получил выборку и передал в шаблон.
внутри **frontend/widgets** создаю папку **views** и кладу туда файл **header.php** — это и есть шаблон

```
<div>
  <?foreach($rows as $row):?>
    <p><?=$row->title?></p>
    <span><?=$row->date_add?></span>
    <p><?=$row->text?></p>
  <?endforeach;?>
</div>
```

В любом шаблоне вызываете

```
<?= frontend\widgets\Header::widget()?>
```

Будет отрендерено вместе с layout'ом, если нужно чисто шаблон, без layout'а, тогда вместо **$this->render** надо использовать **$this->renderPartial**

Comment: Получается если к примеру мне нужно вывести меню, мне с шапки нужно вынести его в папку frontend/widgets, а в самой шапке что-то вроде <?= frontend\widgets\CustomMenu::widget()?> Правильно ?

Comment: Да вы куда угодно можете его вынести, у вас есть классы, вы от них наследуетесь. Я вам написал уже готовый код.

Comment: Ок, понял, спасибо.